# How to eliminate "flash of unstyled content" like behavior

Tags: jquery, slider

I've got a jquery accordian slider that takes a series of definition lists and turns them into an interactive slider widget.

I'm looking to solve the issue where the slides are listed vertically before the script arranges them into the proper format. Its not as apparent on faster connections, but really obvious on slower ones.

Any ideas on a general approach to mitigate this effect? Does jQuery offer a quick solution method?

Here's my work in progress...

css:

```
.my_slider {visibility:hidden;}
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
jQuery('#slider-1').slider({ 
        autoStart: true, 
        slideInterval: 5000,
        slideNum:false,
}); 
jQuery('.my_slider').show();
```

});

What am I missing? Its not toggling the div's visibility to visible.

Answer (score 2):

Style the definition list in an acceptable, attractive manner. Clone the base markup, make the slideshow markup in memory, and when its rendered, replace the currently showing list.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to set the entire accordion to `display: none;`, and have in its place a placeholder `div` of the same size. You can get as fancy as you like with the placeholder, or just leave it as a blank box; its all personal preference. Set up some jQuery so that as soon as the page loads the temporary div is removed and the accordion is shown.

Comment: I suggest almost it, but with `visibility: hidden`. Using a `div` with the same size of the accordion isn't so clean.

Comment: @Erik - I disagree. In this case, we want to completely remove the accordion from the layout (and instead show the placeholder div) until it's ready, at which point we'll put it back in. Using `visibility: hidden` will still allow it to take up space in the layout, which is exactly what we don't want; that's why we have a placeholder.

Comment: @ErickPetru: The benefit of using a placeholder div is that, as eykanal and two7s_clash point out, you can put *something* there rather than just leaving it empty.  Though if you're going to leave it as a blank box, I don't see the point of not just using `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: The questioner didn't say anything about show something in place during the loading of the list. He only asked to not display the list. And it can be obtained easily only with `visibility: hidden`. If he wants to display something in place, as a gif loading, then the div placeholder makes sense. I pointed out that isn't the best solution just because he isn't asked for it.